# scipy ND Interpolating over NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, python-xarray

I have been trouble working out how to use the scipy.interpolate functions (either LinearNDInterpolator, griddata or Preferably NearestNDInterpolator)

There are some tutorials online but i am confused what form my data needs to be in.
The online documentation for nearestND is terrible.

The function asks for:

```
    x : (Npoints, Ndims) ndarray of floats
         Data point coordinates.
    y : (Npoints,) ndarray of float or complex
         Data point values.
```

I have data in the form: lat,long,data,time held within an xarray dataset. There are some gaps in the data I would like to fill in.

I don't understand how to tell the function my x points. 
i have tried (lat,long) as a tuple and np.meshgrid(lat,long) but can't seem to get it going.

Any help on how i can pass my lat,long coordinates into the function? Bonus points for time coordinates as well to make the estimates more robust through the third dimension.

Thanks!

Comment: What has `NaN` anything to do with this question (besides being in the title)?

Comment: Could you add an example of data, what you have tried and the errors that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy provides [multivariate interpolation methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) for both unstructured data and data point regularly placed on a grid. Unstructured data means the data could be provided as a list of non-ordered points. It seems that your data is structured: it is an array of size (480, 2040). However, the `NearestNDInterpolator` works on unstructured data. The `flatten` method can be used to transform the array to a list (1d) of value (of length 480*2040). The same have to be done for the coordinates. `meshgrid` is used to have the coordinates for every points of the grid, and again `flatten` is used to obtain a "list" of 2d coordinates (an array of shape 480*2040 x 2).

Here is an example which go from structured data to unstructured:

```
import numpy as np

lat = np.linspace(2, 6, 10)
lon = np.linspace(5, 9, 14)

latM, lonM = np.meshgrid(lat, lon)  # M is for Matrix

dataM = np.sin(latM)*np.cos(lonM)  # example of data, Matrix form

from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator

points = np.array((latM.flatten(), lonM.flatten())).T
print( points.shape )
# >>> (140, 2)

f_nearest = NearestNDInterpolator(points, dataM.flatten())
f_nearest(5, 5)
```

Working with NaNs should not be a big problem in this case, because it is just a missing point in the list, except that the coordinates of the missing points have to be removed from the list too.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much for your help and explanation. Seems to be working!
Looks like I thought the function did something a little bit different. CloughTocher2DInterpolator, RectBivariateSpline and interp2d look like they might do this?

Are there any functions that can help me fill the whole dataset in automatically, rather than me having to go through pixel at a time with this method?

Answer (score 1):

> i have tried (lat,long) as a tuple

If `lat` and `long` are 1D arrays or lists, try this:

```
points = np.array((lat, long)).T # make a 2D array of shape Npoints x 2
nd = NearestNDInterpolator(points, data)
```

The you can compute interpolated values as `nd(lat1, long1)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, they are 1D lists. This had me really excited, but it still doesn't seem to work.


ValueError: different number of values and points

Doesn't matter what order or form, its the same error.
My tuple is (lat [480],long [2040])
the data is the same: (480, 2040). It looks like this should working but it doesn't feel like it today.

Comment: @NicPittman _"My tuple is `(lat [480],long [2040])` the data is the same: `(480, 2040)`"_. It is not clear at all what 480 and 2040 represent. You really need to update your question with a more detailed example of data and how you call your functions.